# Finding data type of columns in created table

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to provide a service for user validation of table structures, one component of which is column data type, like `uuid`, `text`, and `bigint` in the `CREATE TABLE' statement below.

```
USE my_keyspace;
CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid,
    name text,
    age bigint);
```

If I do

```
USE system;
SELECT validator FROM schema_columns
WHERE keyspace_name='my_keyspace' AND columnfamily_name='users';
```

I get

```
org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType
org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType
```

Which seems informative, but on closer inspection, multiple distinct datatypes can map to the same validator value. Is there a way I can pull the data type info as entered in the `CREATE TABLE' statement, or at least find some distinction between the types?

Also, I'm curious as to why the validator data has the 'org.apache.cassandra...' prepended to it, and couldn't find an explanation, so if anybody knows why that is, I'd be very interested to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which seems informative, but on closer inspection, multiple distinct datatypes can map to the same validator value.

If this is the case, as for example with varchar and text, I believe that the data types map on one another and are interchangeable. Anyone else correct me if I am wrong.

> Is there a way I can pull the data type info as entered in the `CREATE TABLE' statement, or at least find some distinction between the types?

The only way I know would be:

```
DESC TABLE users;
```

> Also, I'm curious as to why the validator data has the 'org.apache.cassandra...' prepended to it, and couldn't find an explanation, so if anybody knows why that is, I'd be very interested to know.

Cassandra is implemented in Java and this is the full path to the Class that implements the data type.

More info:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/marshal

Answer (score 3):

Use following query:

```
select column_name,type from system_schema.columns where keyspace_name ='my_keyspace' AND table_name='users';
```